# Dropping 1st color, switching between 2 others

Tags: javascript, css

What I am trying to do here is, after the **1st** play svg is pressed, that color will stay removed. https://jsfiddle.net/x0pu2c31/

Where **2** other colors would flip back and forth between each other.

They are **Blue** now.

After one is pressed.

Have it switch between 2 chosen colors.

Green & Orange as an example.

**Currently** in the code, the colors change between Blue & Green.

How would I remove the Blue, and have the colors change between Green & Orange after the Blue is removed?

**Like this:**

**Blue** is pressed

Color comes back **Green**,

**Green** is pressed,

Color comes back **Orange**.

**Orange** is pressed,

Color comes back **Green**.

**How the code works is,** you click on the play svg, then you **click on the X to close the page** and go back.'

```
.played {
  fill: green;
}

function markAsPlayed(played) {
    played.classList.toggle("played");
}
```

```js
const manageUI = (function makeManageUI() {

    function resetBackground(backgroundSelector) {
        const allBackgrounds = document.querySelectorAll(backgroundSelector);

        function showBackground(background) {
            background.classList.remove("bg1");
        }
        allBackgrounds.forEach(showBackground);
    }

    function resetCurtains(curtainSelector) {
        const allCurtains = document.querySelectorAll(curtainSelector);

        function showCurtain(curtain) {
            curtain.classList.remove("active");
        }
        allCurtains.forEach(showCurtain);
    }

    function showAllButtons(buttonSelector) {
        const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

        function showButton(button) {
            button.classList.remove("hide");
        }
        allButtons.forEach(showButton);
    }

    function resetButtons(buttonSelector) {
        const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

        function showButton(button) {
            button.classList.remove("isOpen");
        }
        allButtons.forEach(showButton);
    }

    function resetPage() {
        resetBackground("body");
        resetCurtains(".with-curtain");
        showAllButtons(".container.hide");
        resetButtons(".outer");
    }

    function hideCurtains(exitButtons) {
        const container = exitButtons.closest(".inner-container");
        const curtains = container.querySelector(".sliding-panels");
        curtains.classList.add("hide");
    }

    function exitClickHandler(evt) {
        resetPage();
        hideCurtains(evt.currentTarget);
    }

    function addClickToExit(exitButtons) {
        exitButtons.forEach(function addExitButtonHandler(exitButtons) {
            exitButtons.addEventListener("click", exitClickHandler);
        });
    }

    function init() {
        const exitButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
        addClickToExit(exitButtons);
    }

    return {
        init
    };
}());

const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
    const config = {};

    function show(el) {
        el.classList.remove("hide");
    }

    function hide(el) {
        el.classList.add("hide");
    }

    function hideAll(elements) {
        elements.forEach(hide);
    }

    function resetBackground(backgroundSelector) {
        const allBackgrounds = document.querySelectorAll(backgroundSelector);

        function hideBackground(background) {
            background.classList.add("bg1");
        }
        allBackgrounds.forEach(hideBackground);
    }

    function resetButtons(buttonSelector) {
        const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

        function hideButton(button) {
            button.classList.add("isOpen");
        }
        allButtons.forEach(hideButton);
    }

    function resetPage() {
        resetBackground("body");
        resetButtons(".outer");
    }

    function markAsPlayed(played) {
        played.classList.toggle("played");
    }

    function showCovers(playButton) {
        const cover = playButton.parentElement;
        cover.classList.add("active");
        show(cover);
    }

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        hideAll(config.containers);
        resetPage();
        markAsPlayed(evt.currentTarget);
        const cover = evt.currentTarget;
        showCovers(cover);
    }

    function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
        playButtons.forEach(function playButtonHandler(playButton) {
            playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
        });
    }

    function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
        const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
        cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
    }

    function init(selectors) {
        config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
        const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
        addClickToButtons(playButtons);
    }

    return {
        init
    };
}());

    manageCover.init({
        container: ".container",
        playButton: ".thePlay"
    });

    manageUI.init({});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
  animation: fade 2s ease 0s forwards;
}


@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 290px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  gap: 10px;
}

.outer.isOpen {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: 2;*/
}


.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

body.bg1 {
  animation: fadebody 5s ease 0s forwards;
}
 
.thePlay:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(43, 179, 20, 0.5);
}

.thePlay:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.inner-container {
  display: none;
}

/* when container is active hide the svg and show the inner container*/
.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.container.active .inner-container {
  display: flex;
}

.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadebody {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.thePlay {

  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  fill: blue;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.played {
  fill: green;
}



button.thePlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  fill: red;
  padding: 0;
}

.exitsvg {
  fill: none;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
  stroke: #ff0000;
  stroke-width: 17.80202103;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: none;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  border: 4.625px solid #4e4e4e;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 642px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.curtain2 .panel-left::before,
.curtain2 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain3 .panel-left::before,
.curtain3 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain4 .panel-left::before,
.curtain4 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain5 .panel-left::before,
.curtain5 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain6 .panel-left::before,
.curtain6 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain7 .panel-left::before,
.curtain7 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain8 .panel-left::before,
.curtain8 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain9 .panel-left::before,
.curtain9 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain2 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain2 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain3 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain3 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain4 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain4 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}


.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain5 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain5 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain6 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain6 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain7 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain7 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain8 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain8 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain9 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain9 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}


.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;

  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <button class="playa thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <g id="play">
          <title>Play</title>
          <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visiblePainted" />
          <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
                  M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="CHahce95B1g"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <g id="exit">
            <title>exit</title>
            <path d="M 6.3895625,6.4195626 C 93.580437,93.610437 93.580437,93.610437 93.580437,93.610437" />
            <path d="M 6.3894001,93.6106 C 93.830213,6.4194003 93.830213,6.4194003 93.830213,6.4194003" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play2 with-curtain">
    <button class="playb thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain2">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play3 with-curtain">
    <button class="playc thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain3">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play4 with-curtain">
    <button class="playd thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain4">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play5 with-curtain">
    <button class="playe thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain5">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play6 with-curtain">
    <button class="playf thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain6">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play7 with-curtain">
    <button class="playg thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain7">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play8 with-curtain">
    <button class="playh thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain8">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play9 with-curtain">
    <button class="playi thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain9">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO. Currently your code contains a lot which isn't related to your question. Could you reduce your code to contain only the parts that are relevant?

Comment: It would be difficult to because if I remove something the code will fall apart. Everything is interconnected. I provided a snippet.

Comment: I understand. You could also consider making a small prototype where you try to build the color changing effects and we'll help you with that. The point is: it's very hard to know what to change in your code. And keep in mind that questions on this site also have purpose: helping out people with similar questions. A large part of your code won't help others, but the code about your question might.

Comment: Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Is that better, I reduced the size of the snippet code? I removed all the video stuff from the snippet code that is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you were only toggling the `played` class whenever you click the play button. Let's modify this part.

On the first click you'll only want to add the *played* state, but never remove it (you don't want to return to blue).

Instead, when clicking, check if the `played` class has already been added. If it hasn't, add it. If it has been added, then toggle a new class that overwrites the color. The second class *does* need to be toggled, as you'll want to keep switching between that and the played class.

```
function markAsPlayed(played) {
    played.classList.add("played");
}

function markAsVisited(played) {
    played.classList.toggle("visited");
}

function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    
    hideAll(config.containers);
    resetPage();
    
    if (!cover.classList.contains('played')) {
        markAsPlayed(cover);
    } else {
        markAsVisited(cover);
    }
    showCovers(cover);
}
```

In the CSS I've added an extra class to set the color.

```
.played {
  fill: green;
}

.played.visited {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```js
const manageUI = (function makeManageUI() {

    function resetBackground(backgroundSelector) {
        const allBackgrounds = document.querySelectorAll(backgroundSelector);

        function showBackground(background) {
            background.classList.remove("bg1");
        }
        allBackgrounds.forEach(showBackground);
    }

    function resetCurtains(curtainSelector) {
        const allCurtains = document.querySelectorAll(curtainSelector);

        function showCurtain(curtain) {
            curtain.classList.remove("active");
        }
        allCurtains.forEach(showCurtain);
    }

    function showAllButtons(buttonSelector) {
        const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

        function showButton(button) {
            button.classList.remove("hide");
        }
        allButtons.forEach(showButton);
    }

    function resetButtons(buttonSelector) {
        const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

        function showButton(button) {
            button.classList.remove("isOpen");
        }
        allButtons.forEach(showButton);
    }

    function resetPage() {
        resetBackground("body");
        resetCurtains(".with-curtain");
        showAllButtons(".container.hide");
        resetButtons(".outer");
    }

    function hideCurtains(exitButtons) {
        const container = exitButtons.closest(".inner-container");
        const curtains = container.querySelector(".sliding-panels");
        curtains.classList.add("hide");
    }

    function exitClickHandler(evt) {
        resetPage();
        hideCurtains(evt.currentTarget);
    }

    function addClickToExit(exitButtons) {
        exitButtons.forEach(function addExitButtonHandler(exitButtons) {
            exitButtons.addEventListener("click", exitClickHandler);
        });
    }

    function init() {
        const exitButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
        addClickToExit(exitButtons);
    }

    return {
        init
    };
}());

const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
    const config = {};

    function show(el) {
        el.classList.remove("hide");
    }

    function hide(el) {
        el.classList.add("hide");
    }

    function hideAll(elements) {
        elements.forEach(hide);
    }

    function resetBackground(backgroundSelector) {
        const allBackgrounds = document.querySelectorAll(backgroundSelector);

        function hideBackground(background) {
            background.classList.add("bg1");
        }
        allBackgrounds.forEach(hideBackground);
    }

    function resetButtons(buttonSelector) {
        const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

        function hideButton(button) {
            button.classList.add("isOpen");
        }
        allButtons.forEach(hideButton);
    }

    function resetPage() {
        resetBackground("body");
        resetButtons(".outer");
    }

    function markAsPlayed(played) {
        played.classList.add("played");
    }
    
    function markAsVisited(played) {
        played.classList.toggle("visited");
    }

    function showCovers(playButton) {
        const cover = playButton.parentElement;
        cover.classList.add("active");
        show(cover);
    }

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        const cover = evt.currentTarget;
        
        hideAll(config.containers);
        resetPage();
        
        if (!cover.classList.contains('played')) {
            markAsPlayed(cover);
        } else {
            markAsVisited(cover);
        }
        showCovers(cover);
    }

    function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
        playButtons.forEach(function playButtonHandler(playButton) {
            playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
        });
    }

    function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
        const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
        cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
    }

    function init(selectors) {
        config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
        const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
        addClickToButtons(playButtons);
    }

    return {
        init
    };
}());

    manageCover.init({
        container: ".container",
        playButton: ".thePlay"
    });

    manageUI.init({});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
  animation: fade 2s ease 0s forwards;
}


@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 290px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  gap: 10px;
}

.outer.isOpen {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: 2;*/
}


.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

body.bg1 {
  animation: fadebody 5s ease 0s forwards;
}
 
.thePlay:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(43, 179, 20, 0.5);
}

.thePlay:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.inner-container {
  display: none;
}

/* when container is active hide the svg and show the inner container*/
.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.container.active .inner-container {
  display: flex;
}

.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadebody {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.thePlay {

  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  fill: blue;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.played {
  fill: green;
}

.played.visited {
  fill: orange;
}



button.thePlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  fill: red;
  padding: 0;
}

.exitsvg {
  fill: none;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
  stroke: #ff0000;
  stroke-width: 17.80202103;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: none;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  border: 4.625px solid #4e4e4e;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 642px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.curtain2 .panel-left::before,
.curtain2 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain3 .panel-left::before,
.curtain3 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain4 .panel-left::before,
.curtain4 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain5 .panel-left::before,
.curtain5 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain6 .panel-left::before,
.curtain6 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain7 .panel-left::before,
.curtain7 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain8 .panel-left::before,
.curtain8 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain9 .panel-left::before,
.curtain9 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain2 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain2 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain3 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain3 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain4 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain4 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}


.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain5 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain5 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain6 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain6 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain7 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain7 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain8 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain8 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain9 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain9 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}


.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;

  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <button class="playa thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <g id="play">
          <title>Play</title>
          <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visiblePainted" />
          <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
                  M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="CHahce95B1g"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <g id="exit">
            <title>exit</title>
            <path d="M 6.3895625,6.4195626 C 93.580437,93.610437 93.580437,93.610437 93.580437,93.610437" />
            <path d="M 6.3894001,93.6106 C 93.830213,6.4194003 93.830213,6.4194003 93.830213,6.4194003" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play2 with-curtain">
    <button class="playb thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain2">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play3 with-curtain">
    <button class="playc thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain3">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play4 with-curtain">
    <button class="playd thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain4">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play5 with-curtain">
    <button class="playe thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain5">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play6 with-curtain">
    <button class="playf thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain6">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play7 with-curtain">
    <button class="playg thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain7">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play8 with-curtain">
    <button class="playh thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain8">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play9 with-curtain">
    <button class="playi thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain9">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, and for your advice to reduce the snippet size so it makes it easier for people to help.